# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: shared-library

I am using ubuntu 14.04 64 bit OS
when i am running my verilog code in synopsys vcs it shows me the following error, i think there might some missing packages in ubuntu, i search through but i didn't get nothing related to this
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++` so i have decided to post ths issue in this portal. Kindly help to rectify the issues

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

Comment: 14.04 is years old, and you only have another couple of years of lts. you would be better of looking to update the core o/s.

Answer (score 1):

The version of libstdc++ on your system is incompatible with your version of Synopsys.

Synopsys is only supported in CentOS and SLES (and presumably RedHat) as far as I can tell.  So it is unlikely that any version of Ubuntu will work correctly with it without some messy hacking to get the correct versions of libraries.  (Although a CentOS container to run it in could work.)

Comment: How to solved it under Ubuntu i know there must be some other way to work around it @user10489

Comment: I've listed two work arounds (use a supported OS, or use a container) already, and hinted at a third (basically, recompile the libraries yousrelf, but installing a new OS is easier).  There doesn't have to be another work around just because you want one.  Using vendor software like this is annoying, I feel your pain.